# ¿Cómo se le llama a fingir que se habla un idioma?

Tags: literatura, humor, recurso-retórico

Un ejemplo lo tenemos en este vídeo de Danny Kaye, que recopila escenas de varias de sus películas:

[Fan Tribute - Danny Kaye: Master of Many Many Tongues...Indeed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N4FjoCh2-QE)

[Enlace directo a la parte de "español"](https://youtu.be/N4FjoCh2-QE?t=149)

O en "El gran dictador", de Chaplin:

[The Great Dictator - Fake German Speech Scene (No "Translations")](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o61pWzvQMsU)

Se trata, esencialmente, de imitar la entonación, los sonidos, incluso los gestos de los hablantes del idioma extranjero, tal como los perciben los hablantes del propio idioma, para dar la mera impresión de que se habla en él.

No es una [jitanjáfora](https://dle.rae.es/?id=MUZjPaR), puesto que no hay valor estético, ni palabras claras con poder evocador.

Comment: A los ejemplos citados me recuerdan que puedo añadir al genial comediante uruguayo Ricardo Espalter [hablando en "ruso"](https://youtu.be/p9_R2E8cRQs?t=112).

Comment: ¿Y los Minion (de las películas)?

Comment: @pablodf76 Sí, buen ejemplo. No lo conocía, me he echado unas risas.

Comment: @aparente001 No había caído y es un ejemplo muy conocido y actual. Aunque, en este caso, los _minions_ sueltan de vez en cuando alguna palabra inteligible para hacer alguna gracia. También podría interpretarse como que están usando un extranjerismo entre ellos.

Comment: @cdlvcdlv - De hecho yo me había preguntado si los minions que ejecutaron los detalles de la película vivían en Romania.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si se trata de imitar la fonética y la prosodia de un idioma extranjero (aunque no necesariamente un *determinado* idioma, que el oyente pueda "reconocer"), lo más cercano a esto es el ***grammelot*** (o *gromalot* o *grommelot*):

> ... un estilo de lenguaje utilizado en el teatro satírico, una
>   jerigonza sin sentido (*gibberish*) con elementos macarrónicos y
>   onomatopéyicos, usada en asociación con mímica. El uso satírico de un
>   formato de este tipo puede datar de la *commedia dell'arte* del siglo
>   XVI; el grupo de términos cognados [que la designa] pertenece al siglo
>   XX.

(De *[Grammelot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammelot)*, Wikipedia en inglés, mi traducción)

El término *grammelot* fue popularizado por Dario Fo, quien utilizó esta clase de "imitaciones de lenguaje" en su obra *Misterio Buffo* (1969) y las mencionó y explicó citando su inspiración, el dramaturgo [Angelo Beolco, conocido como Ruzzante](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angelo_Beolco) (1492-1542), [al recibir el Premio Nobel](https://www.nobelprize.org/prizes/literature/1997/fo/lecture/):

> Ruzzante, el verdadero padre de la Commedia dell'Arte, también
>   construyó un lenguaje propio, un lenguaje de y para el teatro, basada
>   en una variedad de lenguas: los dialectos del valle del Po,
>   expresiones en latín, español, incluso alemán, todo ello mezclado con
>   sonidos onomatopéyicos de su propia invención.

En un [artículo periodístico sobre Fo](https://www.elperiodico.com/es/opinion/20161016/dos-miradas-el-grammelot-5502513) se describe un espectáculo con *grammelot*:

> ... el actor italiano interpreta el papel de un ingeniero inglés que
>   explica el funcionamiento de una máquina. Lo entenderán enseguida,
>   tanto si saben inglés como si no. De hecho, lo entenderán mejor si no
>   saben inglés, porque Fo utiliza la técnica del 'grammelot', un recurso
>   escénico que es deudor de la Commedia dell’ Arte y que consiste en
>   simular que hablas una lengua sin utilizar ni una sola palabra de esta
>   lengua. Solo con la música del idioma y una gran magnificencia de
>   gestos.

Los intérpretes del Cirque du Soleil, en un espectáculo llamado "Saltimbanco", emplean también [una mezcla de sonidos y prosodia que semeja un idioma romance](https://www.nytimes.com/2003/05/04/arts/theater-cirque-du-soleil-aiming-too-high.html) y que ellos llaman *Cirquish* o cirqués, pero no parece que le hayan dado un nombre al uso, en general, de esta clase de recurso.

Comment: Pues sí, creo que has dado en el clavo. Recordaba vagamente haber leído que había un término para esto pero no estaba seguro

Comment: "Prisencolinensinainciusol" me salió al encuentro enseguida cuando me puse a buscar. Sería otro ejemplo de *gramellot*.

Comment: @walen Imagino que si este recurso fuera más conocido sería adoptado por el español, aunque sea como extranjerismo, pero no parece que sea muy utilizado.

Comment: @pablodf76 Sí, la canción de Celentano es descrita como "una canción que suena como un inglés americano pero hablado por alguien que no conoce el idioma".

Comment: @walen Una vez hecha la pregunta, la respuesta ha resultado ser una palabra de origen extranjero, usada solo por entendidos. Esta es la forma que se usa en los textos en castellano, como en este ejemplo de ["El teatro italiano: Actas del VII Congreso Nacional de Italianistas"](https://i.imgur.com/tXOYJH4.png), cortesía de [Google Books](https://books.google.es/books?id=YhktDWsqdV0C&lpg=PA269&dq=grammelot&hl=es&pg=PA269#v=onepage&q=grammelot&f=false).